# Join Not Working in Larger Query. It Works by Itself

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a query that works when I try it by itself-

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON
catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.`entity_id` AND
catalog_product_entity_decimal.`attribute_id` = 64 AND catalog_product_entity_decimal.store_id = 2
AND catalog_product_entity.`entity_id` = catalog_product_entity_decimal.`entity_id`
```

However - when I run it in a larger query -  the query never comes back.

Note: When I remove this join the Query works just fine.

Note: I am not looking to optimize this query or anything, I simply want this table join to work so that I can use it in the resultset.

I called the alias **trickprice** the part that does not work.

Can anyone please help me figure out why my query is not working?

**Actual Larger Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
pe.entity_id AS ID,
prodname.value AS NAME, 
pe.type_id AS TYPE,
eas.attribute_set_name AS AttribSetName,
pe.SKU,
Prodprice.value AS Price,
si.qty AS Quantity,
decimal_weight.value AS Weight,
special_shipping_group.value AS ShipGroup,
shipping_price.value AS ShipPrice,
ship_separately.value AS Separately,
ship_dimensional.value AS Dimensional,
black_friday_dropship.value AS BlackFridayDropship,
pvisibility.value AS Visibility,

CASE pstatus.value
WHEN 1 THEN  'Enabled'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Disabled'
ELSE NULL
END AS STATUS, 

sites.web_sites AS Websites,
adlinfo_weight.value AS Product_weight,
adlinfo_length.value AS LENGTH,
adlinfo_width.value AS Width,
adlinfo_height.value AS Height,
adlinfo_diameter.value AS Diameter,
adlinfo_footprint.value AS Footprint,
adlinfo_material.value AS Material_Type,
adlinfo_steel.value AS steel_Notes,
adlinfo_upholstery.value AS upholstery,
adlinfo_foam.value AS Foam_Type,
adlinfo_details.value AS Other_Product_Specs,
jumprope_handle_length.value AS Handle_Length,
jumprope_handle_diameter.value AS Handle_Diameter,
jumprope_construction.value AS Handle_Mechanism,
jumprope_cable_type.value AS Cable_Type,
jumprope_cable_length.value AS Cable_Length,
jumprope_cable_diameter.value AS Cable_Diameter,
jumprope_cable_weight.value AS Cable_Weight,


CASE made_in_usa.value
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS MadeinUSA, 

CASE free_shipping.value
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS FreeShipping, 

CASE free_3.value
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS 3ShipsFree, 

CASE patent_pending.value
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS PatentPending, 

CASE econ_product.value
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS EconProduct, 

specialty_crossfit.value AS Crossfit,
specialty_powerlift.value AS PowerLifting,
specialty_olympic.value AS OlympicLifting,
specialty_gymnastics.value AS Gymnastics,

CASE si.manage_stock
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS ManageStock, 


'' AS Qtyfor_ItemsStatus_to_becomeOutofStock,

CASE si.is_in_stock
WHEN 1 THEN  'Yes'
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
ELSE NULL
END AS StockAvailability ,
Pcategory.Mcategory  AS MainCategory,
Ccategory.Scategory AS SubCategory

FROM catalog_product_entity  AS pe 

**LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS trickprice ON trickprice.`entity_id` =2 AND trickprice.`attribute_id`=64 AND trickprice.`store_id` = 2**

JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item si  ON pe.entity_id = si.product_id
JOIN  eav_attribute_set eas ON  eas.attribute_set_id = pe.attribute_set_id

JOIN 
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 60 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) prodname ON pe.entity_id = prodname.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 258 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_weight ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_weight.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 259 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_length ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_length.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 260 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_width ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_width.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 261 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_height ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_height.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 262 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_diameter ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_diameter.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 263 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_footprint ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_footprint.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 264 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_material ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_material.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 265 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_steel ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_steel.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 266 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_upholstery ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_upholstery.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 267 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) adlinfo_foam ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_foam.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 323 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) jumprope_handle_length ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_handle_length.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 324 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0 ) jumprope_handle_diameter ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_handle_diameter.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 329 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0 ) jumprope_construction ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_construction.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 327 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0 ) jumprope_cable_type ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_cable_type.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 325 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) jumprope_cable_length ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_cable_length.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 326 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0 ) jumprope_cable_diameter ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_cable_diameter.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_varchar.entity_id,pe_varchar.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS pe_varchar ON pe_varchar.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 328 AND pe_varchar.store_id= 0) jumprope_cable_weight ON pe.entity_id = jumprope_cable_weight.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 84 AND pe_int.store_id= 0) pstatus ON pe.entity_id = pstatus.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,oval.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id 
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value oval ON pe_int.value = oval.option_id 
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 155  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) special_shipping_group ON pe.entity_id = special_shipping_group.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 89  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) pvisibility ON pe.entity_id = pvisibility.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 344  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) black_friday_dropship ON pe.entity_id = black_friday_dropship.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 169  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) ship_separately ON pe.entity_id = ship_separately.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 170  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) ship_dimensional ON pe.entity_id = ship_dimensional.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 149  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) made_in_usa ON pe.entity_id = made_in_usa.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 150  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) free_shipping ON pe.entity_id = free_shipping.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 255  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) free_3 ON pe.entity_id = free_3.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 284  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) patent_pending ON pe.entity_id = patent_pending.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,pe_int.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 337  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) econ_product ON pe.entity_id = econ_product.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,oval2.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value oval2 ON pe_int.value = oval2.option_id 
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 238  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) specialty_crossfit ON pe.entity_id = specialty_crossfit.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,oval3.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value oval3 ON pe_int.value = oval3.option_id 
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 241  AND pe_int.store_id=0) specialty_powerlift ON pe.entity_id = specialty_powerlift.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,oval4.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value oval4 ON pe_int.value = oval4.option_id 
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 240  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) specialty_olympic ON pe.entity_id = specialty_olympic.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_int.entity_id,oval5.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS pe_int ON pe_int.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value oval5 ON pe_int.value = oval5.option_id 

WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 239  AND pe_int.store_id= 0) specialty_gymnastics ON pe.entity_id = specialty_gymnastics.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_decimal.entity_id,pe_decimal.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pe_decimal ON pe_decimal.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 64  AND pe_decimal.store_id= 0) Prodprice ON pe.entity_id = Prodprice.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_decimal.entity_id,pe_decimal.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pe_decimal ON pe_decimal.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id  AND ea.entity_type_id = pe_decimal.entity_type_id  
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 216 AND pe_decimal.store_id= 0) shipping_price ON pe.entity_id = shipping_price.entity_id 

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_decimal.entity_id,pe_decimal.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS pe_decimal ON pe_decimal.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id  AND ea.entity_type_id = pe_decimal.entity_type_id  
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 69 AND pe_decimal.store_id= 0) decimal_weight ON pe.entity_id = decimal_weight.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN
(SELECT pe_text.entity_id,pe_text.value
FROM eav_attribute AS ea   
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS pe_text ON pe_text.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id   
WHERE  ea.attribute_id = 268 AND pe_text.store_id= 0 ) adlinfo_details ON pe.entity_id = adlinfo_details.entity_id 


LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ss.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(web.name) AS web_sites 
FROM cataloginventory_stock_status ss LEFT JOIN core_website web ON web.website_id = ss.website_id
GROUP BY ss.product_id) sites  ON sites.product_id = pe.entity_id


LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT cp.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(category.value) AS Mcategory
FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar  category  
JOIN  catalog_category_entity p ON p.entity_id = category.entity_id
JOIN catalog_category_product cp ON cp.category_id = p.entity_id  
WHERE category.attribute_id = 33 AND category.store_id = 0 AND p.parent_id=2
GROUP BY cp.product_id

) Pcategory  ON pe.entity_id = Pcategory.product_id


LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT cp.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(category.value) AS Scategory
FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar  category  
JOIN  catalog_category_entity p ON p.entity_id = category.entity_id
JOIN catalog_category_product cp ON cp.category_id = p.entity_id  
WHERE category.attribute_id = 33 AND category.store_id = 0 AND p.parent_id > 2
GROUP BY cp.product_id

) Ccategory  ON pe.entity_id = Ccategory.product_id
WHERE pe.entity_id = 2
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: (edit) what error message you get from the server?

Comment: The original query without the new join comes back in about 5 minutes. The new join by itself comes back in seconds. The combined query never comes back (I kill it after 30 minutes) even with a limit of 0,1

Comment: if the original query comes back in seconds, is it possible to extend it step by step towards the large version of the query and check at what point things get really slow?

Comment: also - how much data you have? could you make a sample copy of your tables with the least minimum data required for the full query to run and check if it still hangs around for 30 min? maybe even an http://sqlfiddle.com/ example? :D

Comment: Unfortunately I have to run it off of this database, and can not create/edit my own table - But I can tell you that the query should return around 7000 records - and in the table I am joining there are roughly 48k records. There is a combined index on the 3 columns I have my ON clause on as well

Comment: may i take a guess that this is a one-time-only-query? i count 90 joins and if that query is being used more then once, it sure needs a ton of optimization. if you can't edit the local db, can you export the data and make a temp table somewhere else?

Comment: It runs every day actually. It completes in about five minutes and that is fast enough for us, but now we need this additional data from the join. I inherited the query from someone else and do not want to re-write ALL of it - I could export one or two tables, but the amount of time it would take to export all the related tables would be an effort (and then import may fail as well).

What I do not get is that the join works fine by itself with the same data, but in this query - when it is added- the query never actually completes?

Comment: im afraid there are not many alternatives but to rewrite the logic of the query or find a way to test it so it actually gives a result and doesnt hang on you. try to export only the structures of those tables involved and some basic data and make a sqlfiddle out of it - at the moment you are not providing clear and sufficient enough information to go on